# Tangent Space and Dual Numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about exercise 2.8 from Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry" (see page 80):

[image]

Assume $X$ is a scheme over field $k$ and $x \in X$. Then the tangent space $T_x$ is defined as the set of $k(x) = O_{X,x}/m_x$-linear morphisms $m_x/m_x^2 \to k(x)$ (so the dual to $m_x/m_x^2 $).

We denote by $k[\epsilon]:=k[t]/t^2$ the ring of dual numbers.

I have to derive a 1-to-1 correspndence between elements of Tangent space $T_x$ and $k$-morphisms $f: Spec(k[\epsilon]) \to X$ with $f(\{*\})= x$ and $k(x)=k$ (so $x$ rational)

Here I encountered following PROBLEM:

At first glace it seems to be quite sraight forward:

A map $f: Spec(k[\epsilon]) \to X$ induces on stalks the map $f_x: O_{X,x} \to k[\epsilon]=k[t]/t^2$ and

since $f_x(m_x^2) =0$ (because $f_x$ is a ***local*** morphism since $f^{\#}$ is a morphism of local ringed spaces)

and the composition $m_x \subset O_{X,x} \to k[\epsilon]$ induces the map $m_x/m_x^2 \to k[\epsilon]$. If we futhermore quotient out $(t)$ from $k[\epsilon]$ then we obtain a canidate $m_x/m_x^2 \to k[\epsilon] \to k[\epsilon]/(t)=k$.

BUT: the problem is that this map is by construction a zero map since $f_*$ is again a local morphism so $f_x(m_x) \subset (t)$ and by $ k[\epsilon]/(t)=k$ we kill $(t)$.

So our $m_x/m_x^2 \to =k$ is always a zero map.

What is the error in my reasonings? Which construction is expected here to settle the desired correspondence?

Comment: Write $k[\epsilon]=k\oplus k\epsilon$ and consider the map obtained by postcomposition with the projection onto the second factor (you projected onto the first one).